# C# Spawn Windows Form on Cursor

Tags: c#, forms, location

This is probably really easy, but I can't figure it out nonetheless. I am trying to spawn my Windows Form at the cursor's location (upon double-click). I am able to get everything else I need `(`cursorXY`,`clickhandler`)`, but I can't figure out how to edit the form, before or after I `Show()` it.

```
public Form2(int cursorX, int cursorY)
{
    Location = new Point(cursorX, cursorY);
...
```

This doesn't work, I know, because it's referring to its location within its container. I've gathered that by capturing `form.Location` while debugging (it's always 0,0). So editing `Location` doesn't do anything so far. Can I move the container or window?

Comment: Use the PointToScreen() method to convert the mouse position to a screen position, suitable for the form's Location property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `StartPosition` of the form to `Manual`:

```
public Form2(int x, int y)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.Location = new Point(x, y);
}
```

Comment: That's what I needed! Thanks. I do have one other question, though. Do you know how to retrieve the cursor's location relative to the active application? The data I have been retrieving has been desktop absolute, which could cause problems if the user isn't in fullscreen mode of course.

Comment: @Joseph Use the `PointToClient` API.  `this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)`

Comment: Spectacular! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Set StartPosition to Manual

```
public Form2(int x, int y)
{
   ...
   this.Location = new Point(x,y)
   this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
   ...
}
```

[See for more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition.aspx)